# Remove $_GET variable using htaccess in localhost server

Tags: .htaccess

Guys can you help me I want to clean up my url using htaccess.

```
http://localhost/website/index.php?page=directory&id=1

http://localhost/website/directory/1
```

Comment: you could check this tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php it helps you build the rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below rule in your website directory,

```
RewriteEngine On

# neither a directory nor a file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Not working. Is it working even if in localhost server?

Comment: No result means 404 not found or 500 server error or bad gateway or what?

Comment: I am assumed your id variable to be integer only now I've changed the rule in answer please try the edit and reply with exact result shown on browser.

Comment: What if I have an special character like "-" how shoud I consider that?

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php
<a href="directory/1">click</a>

submit.php
<?php 
echo $_GET['id'];
echo $_GET['page'];
 ?>

.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  submit.php?page=$1&id=$2    [NC,L]
```